# Put existing object in ResourceDictionary using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I insert existing object (from static field) into ResourceDictionary in a way that is equivalent to instantiating it there directly, ie. referencing resource with `{StaticResource name}` must return object instance and not some wrapper (like ObjectDataProvider).

Comment: so you want to do the equivalent of `ResourceDictionary.Add(name, [static instance])` using XAML? the question is unclear

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: you should just be able to define it in `<[Any FrameworkElement].Resources>` (like normal)

Comment: you need to reword the question. give a code example of what exactly you want to do or just explain it better.

Comment: Well, the best code example that did exact equivalent of what I wanted you have provided yourself in your second response. Anyway I have found a way in a post below.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately `StaticExtension` does not work in all cases, it looks like it just inserts `StaticExtension` object that is convertible to underlying source but it does not work in all contexts (for example when passing parameter value to markup extension).

Actual value is only inserted when using markup syntax `{x:Static my:Foo.Bar}` but that's only possible for properties while I need collections.

---

It seems I can do that with `StaticExtension` but for some reason not directly inside `Application.Resources`.

```
<x:Static Member="my:MyEnum.One" x:Key="one" />
```

It does work directly inside Resources of other classes and also in Application class if I wrap everything with explicit `<ResourceDictionary>`.

This is the error during compilation for the faulty case:

> Error 3 Program 'X:\y\prog.exe' does not contain a static 'Main'
>   method suitable for an entry point

Also, VS2010 crashed soon after when I started editing MainWindow.xaml.

Comment: I would not say that enum values qualify as "existing objects", of course you can reference static things but that is a massive limitation...

Comment: It's basically same thing/syntax and as you noted it works for both. I don't find this limiting - it's exactly what I have asked for in my question ("from static field").